# Regex optional suffix

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regular expression to validate CSS sizes:

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%)
```

The following sizes are therefore valid:

- 10px
- 10.2px
- 1.5em
- 100%

How can I change the regex to make the unit (em|px|%) optional to allow a number only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply add `?` at the end to make the unit optional.

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%)?
```

As the unit is now optional, this pattern will allow numbers only entities as well.  Be aware however, that doing some will also partial match the content making the following valid.

- 10pt
- 10notvalid

If this is an issue, then you can add the `^` start of string and  `$` end of line string pattern modifiers to restrict the check.

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%)?$
```

Answer (score 1):

Either make the whole group [optional](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%)?
```

or add another [alternative](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for the empty string:

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%|)
```

The optional-group regex will capture `undefined` for number-only values, the other regex will capture the empty string `""`.

Comment: This will also match invalid units e.g. '10.2emmmmmm'. It should only match a number or a number and a *valid* unit.

Comment: @BenFoster: For that, you will need [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), but I assumed you'd use them anyway as your original regex has the same problem.

Comment: In that case there was a bug in my original regex :)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to match `em` OR `px` OR `%` (but optionally) you can simply use the `?`:

```
([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)(em|px|%)?$
```

**edit**

Now I understand the question. Also added the anchor cause of invalid matches.