# Finding the singular or plural form of a word with regex

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have the sentence:

```py
sentence = "A cow runs on the grass"
```

If I want to replace the word `cow` with "some" special token, I can do:

```py
to_replace = "cow"
# A <SPECIAL> runs on the grass
sentence = re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w)({re.escape(to_replace)})(?<!\w\B)", "<SPECIAL>", sentence, count=1)
```

Additionally, if I want to replace it's plural form, I could do:

```py
sentence = "The cows run on the grass"
to_replace = "cow"
# Influenza is one of the respiratory <SPECIAL>
sentence = re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w)({re.escape(to_replace) + 's?'})(?<!\w\B)", "<SPECIAL>", sentence, count=1)
```

which does the replacement even if the word to replace remains in its singular form `cow`, while the `s?` does the job to perform the replacement.

My question is what happens if I want to apply the same in a more general way, i.e., find-and-replace words which can be singular, plural - ending with `s`, and also plural - ending with `es` **(note that I'm intentionally ignoring many edge cases that could appear - discussed in the comments of the question)**. Another way to frame the question would be how can add multiple optional ending suffixes to a word, so that it works for the following examples:

```py
to_replace = "cow"
sentence1 = "The cow runs on the grass"
sentence2 = "The cows run on the grass"
# --------------
to_replace = "gas"
sentence3 = "There are many natural gases"
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can with regular expressions alone. Consider the word "dot", whose plural is "dots". "Dotes" is a word that has nothing to do with the noun "dot", though; it's a form of the verb "dote".

Comment: It sounds like you need a dictionary with all the inflections for the words you'd like to search for.

Comment: And that's ignoring nouns like "ox,oxen",  "fungus, fungi", "datum, data", "genus, genera", "radius, radii", etc. There are lots of ways to form a plural, even if not all of them are productive or common in English.

Comment: This is actually more an NLP problem than regex.

Comment: Good points, thanks! Let's assume, for the sake of the argument, that the only plural  variants a word can appear in end with `s` or `es`.

Comment: You can use the inflection library to generate the plural form and regex search for both forms. (https://pypi.org/project/inflect/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using regular python logic, remember to avoid stretching regexes too much if you don't need to:

```
phrase = "There are many cows in the field cowes"
for word in phrase.split():
    if word == "cow" or word == "cow" + "s" or word == "cow" + "es":
        phrase = phrase.replace(word, "replacement")
print(phrase)
```

Output:

```
There are many replacement in the field replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for the use-case I posted, I can make the [suffix optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19811885/regex-optional-suffix). So it could go as:

```py
re.sub(rf"(?!\B\w)({re.escape(e_obj) + '(s|es)?'})(?<!\w\B)", "<SPECIAL>", sentence, count=1)
```

Note that this would not work for many edge cases discussed in the comments!